# Angular 10: Multiple Error Cannot read property 'length' of undefined when using MatTable Paginator

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, typeerror

I am trying to render a mat-table by fetching the data using an api call. The data is getting rendered on the table but there are multiple errors getting thrown on the console.

Below is the datasource.ts

```
export class ListClientDataSource extends DataSource<Client> {
  data: Client[];
  paginator: MatPaginator;
  sort: MatSort;

  constructor(public clientService:  ClientService) {
    super();
    
    this.clientService.getClientsList().subscribe(result =>{
      this.data = result.data;
   });
  }

  /**
   * Connect this data source to the table. The table will only update when
   * the returned stream emits new items.
   * @returns A stream of the items to be rendered.
   */
  connect(): Observable<Client[]> {
    // Combine everything that affects the rendered data into one update
    // stream for the data-table to consume.
    const dataMutations = [
      observableOf(this.data),
      this.paginator.page,
      this.sort.sortChange
    ];

    return merge(...dataMutations).pipe(map(() => {
      return this.getPagedData(this.getSortedData([...this.data]));
    }));
  }
```

below is componenet.ts

```
export class ListClientComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<Client>;
  dataSource: ListClientDataSource;
  
  constructor(public clientService: ClientService) { 
  }

  /** Columns displayed in the table. Columns IDs can be added, removed, or reordered. */
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'name', 'contact', 'email', 'date', 'iot', 'loc'];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new ListClientDataSource(this.clientService);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.dataSource.data.length);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.table.dataSource = this.dataSource;
  }
}
```

the error occurs in the html component when getting the length in paginator

```
<mat-paginator #paginator 
      [length]="dataSource?.data.length"
      [pageIndex]="0"
      [pageSize]="50"
      [pageSizeOptions]="[25, 50, 100, 250]">
  </mat-paginator>
```

can someone help how to fix these errors.
[image]

Comment: In the class `ListClientDataSource` initialize data with empty array initially `data: Client[] = [];` or add elvis(?) operator safe navigation in HTML `dataSource?.data?.length`

Comment: @Sameer Thank you. I  initialized the array as you mentioned, but after that the data is not getting rendered on the table.

Comment: I found a similar issue on angular's GitHub issue page, [Here is the answer](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11638#issuecomment-395240134). Basically, you need to add `subject` and emit that whenever new data is available so mat-table dataSource will rerender the table.

Comment: Thank you. the data  got updated after I added the Behavior Subject.